# About non-CLT groups of order $pq^2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Lately I've been looking over some results about CLT-groups, and I've stumbled about this theorem.[image: Baskaran]

I don't understand why the index of the normalizer is $p$ (equivalent with saying that every subgroup of order $q$ has $p$ distinct conjugates, by Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem).
If no subgroup H of order $q$ can be normal in G, then it has to be equal to it's normalizer, thus shouldn't the index be equal to $pq$, considering the fact that order of G is $pq^2$ and order of H is $q$ ?

Also, I can't understand why should $q+1$ be divisible by $p$.

Comment: What is "CLT" ?

Comment: CLT is "Converse Lagrange Theorem" - for every divisor $d$ of $|G|$, there exists a subgroup of order $d$.

Comment: Converse-Lagrange-Theorem; groups that satisfy the converse of lagrange theorem

Comment: @Peter Converse Lagrange Theorem. At Math apprentice, do not copy in pictures. Write it out. And mention the source of your question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that's to be proven

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Mathapprentice Your last sentence is not very clear. If $H$ is a subgroup of order $q$, then it lies in a Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of group $G$. Since $|Q|=q^2$, $Q$ is abelian and hence $Q\leq N_G(H)$.

Comment: @kabenyuk Yes, that's right, but also the normalizer is the biggest group in which H is normal. Since H can't be normal, I'm assuming that H is the same with it's normalizer

Comment: @Mathapprentice No, $N(H)$ coincides with its nrmalizer, so $N(N(H))=N(H)>H$.